# How to disable STOP Mode in STM32

Tags: stm32

Hello I use in my code stop mode

`HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_LOWPOWERREGULATOR_ON,PWR_STOPENTRY_WFI);`
the microcontroller goes back to the stop mode, after each EXTI and it is ok. But I use a timer to check for a long button press

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim) {
    UNUSED(htim);
    if(htim->Instance == TIM3) {
        if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(SW1_GPIO_Port, SW1_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_RESET) {
            longPress++;
            if (longPress>=30)
            {
                configurationSetup();
                longPress=0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think it won't work in stop mode. How to prevent from entering the stop mode again?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, don't use:

```
HAL_PWR_EnableSleepOnExit();
```

Indicates Sleep-On-Exit when returning from Handler mode to Thread mode.
Note:
Set SLEEPONEXIT bit of SCR register. When this bit is set, the processor re-enters SLEEP mode when an interruption handling is over. Setting this bit is useful when the processor is expected to run only on interruptions handling.

Or using

```
HAL_PWR_DisableSleepOnExit();
```